# Understanding STATE in angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am new to AngularJS. I tried to read about how states work in angular and different fields present in it, but didn't find any useful materials.
Also AngularJS documentation doesn't explain states in a proper way, so if there are any resources to get good grasp of states in AngularJS.

Comment: which "state" and "fields" are you talking about? Can you give some more precisions? Are you talking about routing?

Comment: do you mean ui-router states? https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki

Comment: Yes, I am talking about ui-router. I am using statePropvider and addding states into that

Answer (score 10, accepted):

State is represented by scope objects.

Angular is a [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)/[MVVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel) like framework where *models* (and *view models*) present the *state* of a certain context. Models object can for instance reflect the state of a database record or can be objects that define the current situation of the user interface.
*Controllers* and *view models* are used to manipulate model state.

Angular model objects are wrapped in [scope](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope) instances, which are assigned to HTML (view) elements. Scopes are like *view models* from MVVM but differ in that they inherit from each other based on nesting of the HTML element.

Some good starter links:

- https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes
- http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts
- http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/3-reasons-to-choose-angularjs-for-your-next-project/